# Replacing missing values with mean from another dataset, by factor

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data-frame like `iris` which I'll be splitting into train and test sets. Previously, I could use `group_by` and `mutate` from dplyr to replace the mean of missing values by the mean of that species within the attribute, for each attribute.

I now realise that correct ML practice requires first splitting into training and test, then I should impute the mean on the test set using the **training means**.

Can anyone help do this?

If unclear, let's take an example with `iris`.

```
iris0 <- iris

iris0[sample(150,50,replace=FALSE),1] <- NA
iris0[sample(150,50,replace=FALSE),2] <- NA
iris0[sample(150,50,replace=FALSE),3] <- NA
iris0[sample(150,50,replace=FALSE),4] <- NA

set.seed(123)
sampled <- sample(150,50,replace=FALSE)
iris_test <- iris0[sampled,]
iris_train <- iris0[-sampled,]
```

Now we come to imputation. I can get the means by class in iris_train:

```
iris_train %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_all(mean,na.rm=TRUE)

1 setosa          5.07        3.49         1.5 
2 versica         5.89        2.84         4.33
3 virginica       6.56        2.97         5.52
```

Now, as I said, filling in NAs in iris_train with these means can be done with dplyr (group-by and mutate). But I would like to replace the NAs in **iris_test** with the same means, i.e. setosa species fill in any NA in the Sepal.Length column with 5.07, versica species with 5.89, virginica fills in any NA in the Sepal.Width column with 2.97 etc.

Only base-R and dplyr please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can store the results of mean in  `iris_mean`, `left_join` it with `iris_test` and replace the `NA` values.

```
iris_mean <- iris_train %>% group_by(Species) %>% summarise_all(mean,na.rm=TRUE)
temp <- iris_test %>%  left_join(iris_mean, by = 'Species')
col1 <- 1:4
col2 <- 6:9
temp[col1][is.na(temp[col1])] <- temp[col2][is.na(temp[col1])]
temp[1:5]
```

Comment: As I said, I know how to do this. I am wondering how to use iris_train's means, to replace the NAs, in iris_test. This is proper statistical practice